# ¿Cómo saber la versión de node que utiliza Electron?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Me gustaría saber cual es la versión de node.js que esta utilizando [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)

Se supone que debe consultar `process.versions` como se menciona en la respuesta a este issue https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/3068#issuecomment-147371584 pero no entiendo a que se refieren.

Comment: has intentado ver que te sale si haces `console.log(process.versions)`? ese objeto tiene diferentes propiedades con las versiones de los diferentes componentes de node.... Fijate aquí: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_versions

Comment: en esta liga puedes ver como consultarlo http://zuri.website/blog/electron/2015/07/21/electron-versions.html

Comment: @KristianDamian ya entendí como lograrlo gracias a ese enlace. Publicaré una respuesta en base a eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de revisar las versión de node que utiliza Electron la encontré en [Electron versions](http://zuri.website/blog/electron/2015/07/21/electron-versions.html) gracias al comentario de @KristianDamian.

Para saber la versión se debe ejecutar `process.version.node` en la consola DevTools de una aplicación Electron. Para abrir DevTools se debe utilizar el metodo `openDevTools()` de `BrowserWindow`.

Por ejemplo para que este disponible DevTools en la aplicación de electron:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Crea la ventana
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

  // carga index.html
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/app/index.html');

  // Abre Dev Tools
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Y dentro de la consola de la aplicación de electron, ejecuto:

```
> process.versions.node
< "5.1.1"
```

Y si por ejemplo también quiero saber la versión de Chromium y de electron

```
process.versions.chrome
process.versions.electron // otra forma es con electron -v en la terminal
```